# Getting elements with default namespace (no namespace prefix) using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xpathquery, default-namespace

In this SOAP XML file, how can I get the `7` on a using a XPath query?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <HelloWorldResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
           <HelloWorldResult>7</HelloWorldResult>
        </HelloWorldResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This XPath query is not working `//*[name () ='soap:Body']`.

Comment: what are you trying to extract?

Comment: missing < . but is not the problem. i want  number 7

Answer (score 38):

If you have a namespace prefix set, you could use it, like:

```
//soap:Body
```

But since the nodes you are trying to get use a **default namespace**, without a prefix, using plain XPath, you can only acesss them by the `local-name()` and `namespace-uri()` attributes. Examples:

```
//*[local-name()="HelloWorldResult"]/text()
```

Or:

```
//*[local-name()="HelloWorldResult" and namespace-uri()='http://tempuri.org/']/text()
```

Or:

```
//*[local-name()="HelloWorldResponse" and namespace-uri()='http://tempuri.org/']/*[local-name()="HelloWorldResult"]/text()
```

To your xml, they will all give the same result, the text `7`.

Comment: **Note:** If you were using a tool to execute the XPath, you could specify the namespace for that query and proceed as usual (without the workarounds above). Needless to say, each tool has a specific way of setting that.

Comment: Does this syntax only work if the node with xmlns="whatever" is the last node?  I've tried this repeated times today and can't get it to work.

Comment: @Kyralessa, no, it should work wherever the node is. Maybe it is your tool. Try it online, see how it works here: http://goo.gl/HJMcgM

Comment: I figured out my problem.  I had to use the alias all the way down: `root/abc:nodeWithXmlns/abc:thisOne/abc:theOneIWant`

Comment: @Kyralessa Yes, in some tools, that'd work. Great, then!