# extracting a value from XML using SQL using Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm trying to extract values from XML that is coming back from a web service call. However, the inclusion of the "xmlns" attribute is causing my query to not work as expected.

This query works as expected, I get "Y" back:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLType('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string><SAMP_OVERALL>Y</SAMP_OVERALL></string>')
, 
'/string/SAMP_OVERALL') myval
from dual;
```

Here is the same query but the root tag "string" contains the xmlns attribute. This is how the actual XML comes back. I narrowed down it is the attribute giving me trouble. It returns null:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLType('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="someweburl"><SAMP_OVERALL>Y</SAMP_OVERALL></string>')
, 
'/string/SAMP_OVERALL') myval
from dual;
```

Why does the inclusion of the xmlns attribute cause this not to return the value of the SAMP_OVERALL tag?

At this point I can't figure out the syntax to pull out the values that I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  EXTRACTVALUE(XMLType(
     q'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <string xmlns="http://someweburl"><SAMP_OVERALL>Y</SAMP_OVERALL></string>]')
, 
'/*[local-name()="string"]/*[local-name()="SAMP_OVERALL"]') myval
from dual;
```

This answer explains how to extract values using xpath when default namespace without a prefix is defined :
 [Getting elements with default namespace (no namespace prefix) using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717211/getting-elements-with-default-namespace-no-namespace-prefix-using-xpath)