# Python XPath with ElementTree Invalidate Predicate

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

I have a probleme to get the max value of CategoryLevel 
I write this but it says Invalidate Predicate.

`document=xmlParser.parse("Categories.xml")`

```
xpathQuery="{0}CategoryArray/{0}Category[not({0}CategoryArray/{0}Category/{0}CategoryLevel>{0}CategoryLevel)]".format(namespace)

categories=root.find(xpathQuery)
```

> The xml file

```
<GetCategoriesResponse xmlns="urn:xxxxxxxx:xxxxx:xxxxxxxx">
<CategoryArray>
    <Category>          
        <CategoryLevel>1</CategoryLevel>            
    </Category>
    <Category>
        <CategoryLevel>2</CategoryLevel>    
    </Category>
    <Category>          
        <CategoryLevel>3</CategoryLevel>            
    </Category>
    <Category>
        <CategoryLevel>2</CategoryLevel>    
    </Category>
```

I want to check if this xpath query is suitable to extract the maximum value of categoryLevel or not, and i don't understand the answer of the other post.
Could you please tell me the source of my error?!
Cordially

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting elements with default namespace (no namespace prefix) using XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717211/getting-elements-with-default-namespace-no-namespace-prefix-using-xpath)

Comment: I want to check if this xpath query is suitable to extract the maximum value of categoryLevel or not, and i don't understand the answer of the other post. Could you please tell me the source of my error?! Cordially